# Unknown plugin "static-fs" specified in .babelrc?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, babeljs

I am trying to run [the exhibits](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/tree/master/exhibits) in deck.gl project. I have cloned the repo, switched to the `exhibits` directory, and run:

```
npm run browserify
```

This installs the packages without errors, and runs the project, but when the browser opens I see the following error:

```
Unknown plugin "static-fs" specified in "/Users/me/Projects/deck.gl/.babelrc" at 0, 
attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/me/Projects/deck.gl" 
while parsing file: /Users/me/Projectss/deck.gl/exhibits/app.js
```

So the problem is [the `.babelrc` file](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/.babelrc#L4):

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "static-fs",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

What should I do? Google isn't suggesting any answers, and `static-fs` doesn't appear to be a package.

Comment: This _looks_ like the right package https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-static-fs

Comment: Thanks. I installed it and `babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy` using npm, and added both packages to devDependencies, but I'm still seeing the same error. I also tried changing the config setting to `babel-plugin-static-fs` but that throws an error too :(

Comment: Those packages are in the `package.json` located at the project's root. Have you run `npm install` at the root, too?

Comment: @cartant THANK YOU! That was the problem :) If you want to submit as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the [`package.json`](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/exhibits/browserify/package.json) in the `exhibits/browserify` directory,
the **deck.gl** project includes a [`package.json`](https://github.com/uber/deck.gl/blob/master/package.json) at the project's root.

Note that there are packages in the root file that are not in the `exhibits/browserify` file.

It's necessary to run `npm install` at the root, too, as the 'missing' dependencies will resolve back to the root `node_modules` directory.